# Creating corpora for tgrep2 from bracket-delineated trees

Tags: text, binary, nlp, corpus

How do I create a tgrep2-able corpus file from bracket- (or roundbrace-) delineated trees in a text file? I've done a bit of looking now and only see how to convert from tgrep to tgrep2 filetypes. TFM has been no help, nor has much googling. I just want to convert my corpora to t2c files or whatever.